# vimeo app upload access

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have created an vimeo app and idea is to upload video on different peoples account using the app if user gives upload access to the app. Now the problem is no matter what permission i set in my authorization link, app never gets upload access for other user, if i try to authorize the app with same user as app owner then only it get upload access. Is it something that vimeo wont let app to do or is there special tweaks.
By the way i am using oAuth 1.0 and i have vimeo pro account.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo upload permissions clarify which types of accounts can upload via your app.

- Owner means only you
- PRO means only pro users
- Plus means only plus users
- Basic means only basic users

You can have zero to all of these permissions, and you can verify them on your app page. It's likely that the third party users you are communicating with do not line up with your upload permissions.